# Can you change where the text editors file tab positions are in Aptana?

Tags: aptana

Im running Aptana IDE for developing on a lamp setup. I have looked all over the place in the options to try and find if I can move the text editors file tabs to the side instead of lined up along the top. Any googling I attempt for this just gives me results for changing tab widths and stuff like that, so im having to ask the question here instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look possible. That would be a limitation of the underlying Eclipse platform on top of which Aptana is built. You could file a feature request here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, ill live with it as it is for now.

Answer (score 0):

This was possible in Aptana 3.4.2. (at least to have them on the bottom) - however I can't find it in 3.6.0. so it looks like it's no longer possible.